# wordpress query_posts not working as expected with minus sign

Tags: wordpress

im using wp_query to query posts from a certain taxonomy as followed :

```
        $location=urldecode($_GET['location']);
        $property_type=urldecode($_GET['propertyType']);

        query_posts(array(
                    'numberposts'=>-1,
                    'post_type'=>'property',
                    'property-type'=>$property_type,
                    'location'=>$location,
                    'meta_query'=>array(
                        array('key'=>'wpcf-price','value'=>$amount[0],'compare'=>'>=','type' => 'numeric'),
                        array('key'=>'wpcf-price','value'=>$amount[1],'compare'=>'<=','type' => 'numeric')
                    ),
                    'suppress_filters'=>false
        ));
```

it is working as expected most of the time except for this string (which is

> תל - אביב יפו

it seems that the minus sign somehow messes up the search,
how can i solve this ?

is there a way to use a "LIKE" statement here ?

Comment: What minus sign? Where does that string appear? Where do you want to use LIKE?

Comment: Can you define "somehow messes up" a little more precisely for us?

Comment: this is the string $location
and it holds "תל - אביב יפו" , by "messes up" i mean the results are wrong (no results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem,

I queried the location meta using the $term->name instead of $teadm->slug which solved the issue.